# Diophantine equation $a^3+a=b^2+1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I have this Diophantine:
$$ a^3+a=b^2+1 $$
I found $a=2$, $b=3$ works.
Also $a=13$ , $b=47$ works.
How can I find all the integer solutions?

Comment: Clearly, b is odd. Another solution a=1,b=±1

Comment: $a=\frac{b^2+1}{a^2+1}=\frac{(b^2+1)(a^2+1)}{(a^2+1)^2}=\frac{(ab±1)^2+(a∓b)^2}{(a^2+1)^2}=(\frac{ab±1}{a^2+1})^2+(\frac{a∓b}{a^2+1})^2$, so $a$ must be sum of two squares.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/integer-solutions-of-n2n1-m3

Comment: As b is odd, $b^2≡1(mod\ 8)=>b^2+1≡2(mod\ 8)$. Now $a^3+a(modulo\ 8)$ are 2 only for $a≡1,2 or 5(mod\ 8)$

Comment: It's just an elliptic curve, and there's a lot of theory about it. Try searching for integral points on elliptic curves.

Answer (score 4):

Using MAGMA and the method described by Pete L. Clark [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30501/%E2%80%A6) one finds the complete set of integer solutions is

$(1 , -1), (2 , 3), (13, -47), (1 , 1), (2 , -3), (13 , 47)
$

Comment: The first and third entries are not solutions.

Comment: I posted the wrong list before. Here is the corrected list.

Comment: Well, I assumed it was a problem in using the software. Thanks for the update.